# cmake: подключение библиотеки к библиотеке

Tags: cmake, mingw, msbuild, msys2

Прошу помощи в конфигурации cmake. Сегодня первый день вожусь с cmake и сабж не получается.
Делаю тестовый проект, структура его такова:

```
C:\Projects\c++\TestSFTP\
 ├─ main.cpp
 ├─ CMakeLists.txt (1)
 └─ sftp++\
     ├─ sftp_auth.cpp
     ├─ sftp_tools.cpp
     ├─ sftp++.cpp
     ├─ sftp_auth.h
     ├─ sftp_defs.h
     ├─ sftp++.h
     └─ CMakeLists.txt (2)
```

*CMakeLists.txt (1)*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(TestSFTP LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
 
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
 
set(SOURCE_EXE main.cpp)

include_directories(sftp++)

add_executable(TestSFTP ${SOURCE_EXE})

add_subdirectory(sftp++)

target_link_libraries(TestSFTP sftp++)
```

*CMakeLists.txt (2)*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(sftp++)

set(SOURCE_LIB
      sftp++.cpp
      sftp_auth.cpp
      sftp_tools.cpp
)

set(HEADER_LIB
      sftp++.h
      sftp_defs.h
      sftp_auth.h
)

if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    set(BITS x64)
elseif()
    set(BITS x32)
endif()

message("Bits ${BITS}")

add_library (sftp++ STATIC ${SOURCE_LIB} ${HEADER_LIB})
```

Пока все линкуется и собирается. Но мне нужно подключить внешнюю либу `libssh2` к моей собираемой `sftp++`, а она у меня находится тут для `shared`:

- C:/Projects/c++/libssh2/vs-x64-shared/bin
- C:/Projects/c++/libssh2/vs-x64-shared/include
- C:/Projects/c++/libssh2/vs-x64-shared/lib

Или тут для `static`:

- C:/Projects/c++/libssh2/vs-x64-static/include
- C:/Projects/c++/libssh2/vs-x64-static/lib

**Собственно, вопрос**

Куда и что прописать, чтобы создаваемая мною либа `sftp++` могла использовать `libssh2` (статически и динамически)?

И попутно ... в конфиге я определяю битность, в которую собирается проект.
А можно ли как-то подобным образом определить `static/shared` и `MSVC/mingw`?

Comment: 1) [2 команды для подключения есть в доках](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/master/docs/INSTALL_CMAKE.md); 2) Вы определяете `STATIC/SHARED` сами при указании `add_library`, например `add_library(my_lib STATIC)`, а для внешних библиотек с помощью задокументированных опций (например, `set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)` перед `find_package`); 3) Проверяете переменные [MINGW](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/MINGW.html) и [MSVC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/MSVC.html).

Comment: Огромное спасибо!